# Can't open R studio error "retrieving package installation contex"

Tags: r, rstudio

I can't open r studio.
I tried to start R studio. First the statdart Windows error is appear

> RStudio R Session has stopped working

I choose "Close the program". Then Rstudio starting with error

> R encaunared fatal error
>
> This session was terminated

But session continues. Next appear "null" and continues. After that appear error

> retrieving package installation contex

It is continues long time. After hard closing of session the same situation is repeated.
Before that bad cicle R studio was closed with `q()` command. And computer was restarted.
How to exit from that cicle?

Comment: If restarting Rstudio doesn't help, reinstalling it might? My suggestion would be to use a daily build https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: Because I'm noit a administrator of the computer the reinstaling I tried to find other. Reinstalling is with sheduling of administration and so on...

Comment: I replaced '.Rhistory' file with old version of the file and RStudio started correctly.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. Solution is a bit unexpected for me, a history file breaks breaking the whole IDE...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `.Rhistory` file (in working directory) with old version of the file and RStudio started correctly.